# Iterating over a dictionary of lists using 'for' loop to return price < certain amount and append to list and then output to csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having trouble appending the list to add the correct values it is not returning loans <500 but rather all of them when I output list to csv file... it also returns none when i try to print the list...I know I am doing some thing wrong but not sure exactly what.

Here are the instructions...

Create a new, empty list called `inexpensive_loans`.
Use a for loop to select each loan from a list of loans.
a. Inside the for loop, write an if-statement to determine if the loan_price is less than or equal to 500
b. If the loan_price is less than or equal to 500 then append that loan to the `inexpensive_loans` list.
Print the list of inexpensive_loans.

```
loans = [
{
    "loan_price": 700,
    "remaining_months": 9,
    "repayment_interval": "monthly",
    "future_value": 1000,
},
{
    "loan_price": 500,
    "remaining_months": 13,
    "repayment_interval": "bullet",
    "future_value": 1000,
},
{
    "loan_price": 200,
    "remaining_months": 16,
    "repayment_interval": "bullet",
    "future_value": 1000,
},
{
    "loan_price": 900,
    "remaining_months": 16,
    "repayment_interval": "bullet",
    "future_value": 1000,
},
]

inexpensive_loans = [] 
for loan_price in loans:     
    if (loan_price['loan_price']) <= 500:

    inexpensive_loans.append(loan_price[inexpensive_loans])

print(inexpensive_loans)


header = ["loan_price", "remaining_months", "repayment_interval", "future_value"]

output_path = Path("inexpensive_loans12345.csv")



print("writing csv file...")
csvpath = Path("inexpensive_loans12345.csv")
with open(csvpath, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)

csvwriter.writerow(header)

for row in loans:
    csvwriter.writerow(row.values())
```

Comment: Change this `inexpensive_loans.append(loan_price[inexpensive_loans])` to `inexpensive_loans.append(loan_price)`

Comment: got it: thank you...just need to get that list outputed to csv file: edit I think I got it....just change second to last line "for row in loans:" to "for row in inexpensive_loans:

Answer (score 0):

To use a for loop to create the `inexpensive_loans` list here's how to write it better:

```
inexpensive_loans = [] 
for loan in loans:     
    if loan['loan_price'] <= 500:
        inexpensive_loans.append(loan['loan_price'])
print(inexpensive_loans)
```

Alternatively, I suggest that you rewrite the for loop into a list comprehension for better readability:

```
inexpensive_loans = [loan['loan_price'] for loan in loans if loan['loan_price'] <= 500]
```

In either case, you should get `[500, 200]` as the output.